# Excel TIME duration over 24 hours

Tags: excel

Data is:

```
A1 = 29. B1 = 30. C1 = 2. 

D1 = TIME(A1, B1, C1).
```

How can I get D1 to return `29:30:02`?

Formatting the D1 cell to [hh]:mm:ss does NOT work!

If I ran for 29 hours in a month, Excel thinks I ran for only 5 hours.

Thank you.

Edit: Thank you!! I got it!!! `D1 = TIME(A1, B1, C1) + INT(A1 / 24)`

Comment: how do you expect this to behave with higher values? we don't have 29 hours in a day so with time() excel does what you'd expect and takes 24 hours into account
29:30:02 conceptually doesn't make sense, so you might want to rethink your desired output. (you could check for 24 hour periods and count days as well as a time)

Comment: @Chrisvdberge if I ran for 29 hours in a month, Excel thinks I ran for 5 hours.

Comment: I had a similar (same! running ;)) example and in the end went with hours in decimal way. so in your case i'd say I ran 29,5 hours 
but that's just preference I think and depending on how you want to work with the output (do you graph it, use it in calculations..)

Answer (score 1):

The result you get is exactly how [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457) works:

> **Hour**    Required. A number from 0 (zero) to 32767 representing the
>   hour. Any value greater than 23 will be divided by 24 and the
>   remainder will be treated as the hour value. For example, TIME(27,0,0)
>   = TIME(3,0,0) = .125 or 3:00 AM.

You could do

`=A1/24+B1/24/60+C1/24/60/60` in `D1`

Then the resulting value formatted as `[hh]:mm:ss` will show `29:30:02`.

That is because 1 is 1 day in `Excel`. So 1/24 is 1 hour, 1/24/60 is 1 minute and 1/24/60/60 is 1 second.

[image]

Comment: nice one. You'll still be able to calculate with this so this is preferred solution i'd say

Answer (score 0):

Time is trying to give you clock time so 29hrs=5am.
So if you want that result how about just:

```
D1=CONCATENATE(A1,":",B1,":",C1)
```

If then you want the 02 you would have to interject a little formatting to those columns...

Comment: this indeed answers the (literal) question, but I wonder if this is truly what he wants (or should want ;))

Comment: @Chrisvdberge I want D1 to resemble 29 hours, 30 minutes, and 2 seconds in the display of 29:30:02. Many people have suggested changing the format to [hh]:mm:ss , this doesn't work

Comment: Well I was only trying to help. We sometimes have long term experiments and jus wish to generate the x-axis in this way. So it works for that.  If the idea is to then manipulate the “time” you obviously have to then unwrap that with some string to number processing.

Comment: @RichardBJ his answer is doing exactly what you want so go with that then I'd say. Time is not useful for this as it is time of day and therefor counts in 24 hour cycles

Comment: And if you want to use this method to produce a time value, just add some formatting code and a double unary to convert to a number:  `=--CONCATENATE(A1,TEXT(B1,"\:00\:"),TEXT(C1,"00"))`

Answer (score 0):

Very similar [solution as given above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53129906/3419573) by [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) is shown in support article [Add or subtract time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad) by Microsoft.

Basically it boils down to using custom format of `[h]:mm;@`. However I am not sure, what the exact difference to `[hh]:mm:ss` (or more precisely to `[hh]:mm`) is - if at all? A quick check in Excel did not reveal any differences to me.

However, as the support article covers topic of adding and subtracting of time values pretty comprehensively, I hope it will be useful to be cited here.